# How to Pivote grid view in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

Hi I have a list and it is set as a data source for a grid view. My grid view looks like this.

```
      Green| Gold | Grade  
       ----|----  | -------  
       2   | 1    | 100  
       3   | 1    | 101  
       -   | 3    | 102  
       3   | -    | 104  
       -   | -    | 105  
       8   | 5    | Total
```

But I want like this

```
  Grade   |100  |101 |102 |103 |104 |105 |Total  
--------- |---- |----|----|----|----|----|-----  
  Green   |2    |3   |-   |3   |8   |-   |8  
  Gold    |1    |1   |3   |-   |3   |-   |5
```

This is My List class

```
public class Value
{
    public string Gold { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public string Green { get; set; }
}

public class GetCACPopGuideResult
{
    public object Type { get; set; }
    public List<Value> Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I have done in the code

```
GetCACPopGuideResult result = getvalue();// Get the values to display
GridView1.DataSource= result.Value;

Public GetCACPopGuideResult getvalue()
{
        string URL= myURL;
        var cli = new RestClient(URL);
        IRestRequest auctionRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        IRestResponse responseCustomer = cli.Execute(auctionRequest);
        return responseCustomer.Content;
}
```

Is there a way I can do this in C#? Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting data from DB? then provide SQL else provode getvalue() implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your replay,I have modified the grids.

Comment: It is not from the database. It is from an web service. it just calls a webservice and loads the data thats all. I have added code for that getdata Please look that.

Comment: I think it won't be compiled because you are returning string though return type is GetCACPopGuideResult  in getvalue

Comment: Actually it was a mistake. It will return the class. I have corrected now

Comment: Please copy paste proper code. Don't waste others time being compiler for you.

Comment: Convert this into a structure `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,int>>`, which will give the pivoted data. String key will be `Green / Gold`, internal dictionary key would be 101 - 105 and value will be the Green or Gold quantity. then you can run all  the Pivot operations.

Comment: @BaijuC please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create dynamic objects in LINQ.

What you should do is convert the data you receive in a Dictionary like this example:

```
var dictionary = value
    .GroupBy(v => v.Grade)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
        g => new 
            {
                g.Select(x => x.Gold).FirstOrDefault(),
                g.Select(x => x.Green).FirstOrDefault()
            });
```